# What is the load sequence of page?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, image

One thing i noticed when displaying images using ajax is that images are always the last thing to show on a page, this means that it doesn't load during the success event or even in the complete event of the ajax call.

So after complete event of ajax call...

[image: Ajax call]

Still no image...

[image: No image displayed]

Images will show up after the ajax call in the browser

[image: Image displayed]

This causes problems when you try to calculate the height/width of the container before the image has been loaded. In my case, i tried to layout the masonry in the complete event but obviously it miscalculates the height because the image is yet to be displayed. The problem has been fixed but i want to know:

**What is the load sequence of a page? why is the image the last thing to show even though i added it inside the ajax call?**

**Update how i am displaying the image**

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result.success) {
        $.each(result.postsViewModel.Posts, function (index, item) {
            var post = $('<div class="postItem padding-left-right-20"><div class="ibox"><div class="ibox-content contact-box">' + '<div class="small m-b-xs">' + (item.ImageUrl != null ? '<img width="1000" alt="Post Image" class="img-responsive" src="' + item.ImageUrl + '">' : '<img width="1000" alt="Post Image" class="img-responsive" src="/Images/blog/no-image-available.jpg">');
        });

        //add item
        $(".postList").append($post);

        //add masonry item
        $grid.append($post).masonry("appended", $post);
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using chrome? Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Yes i'm using Chrome, no i haven't, but if it only happens in chrome, why is the load sequence different in different browsers?

Comment: Just because the JavaScript Ajax call has returned successful doesn't mean the browser has had time to render the image.

Comment: @Kaiido Updated

Comment: And so you are expecting that just because you had the `imageURL` from your ajax call, the loading of the image would magically become synchronous ? It won't. Even if these are dataURIs, or blobURIs, or HTTP cached resources, the loading of an ImageElement is **always** asynchronous. You'll have to wait for their onload event.

Comment: @Kaiido wow...don't have to be so aggressive...i'm just asking a question...i want to know why and the load sequence???

Comment: @Kaiido and voting to close and down vote the question doesn't help at all, and why is this off-topic?

Comment: Didn't meant to be aggressive, sorry. Might not have enough coffee in me. But your question is not the correct one. There is no *"load sequence"*. Or if you want it's `yourAjax_getURLS()`=> image.src_setting => image_resource_fecthing (async so all the reamainings are in an unpredictibale order) => image_resource_parsing => imageElement set naturalWidth/naturalHeight => [chrome-only: image-rendering] => onload-event-fires => [non-chrome-only : image-rendering]

Comment: OK thanks, i'll investigate further, i just couldn't find any info about this anywhere, what i ended up doing was to wait for the image to load first, just curious if the image is always the last thing to load or it depends on the size of the image, but on chrome i definitely see all of the images "pop up" at the same time

Comment: And that's all you can do. The only reliable source of info on when an image has loaded (and it doesn't even mean that it has been rendered) is to listen for its `load` event.